# Yaml trigger doesn't work but overridding in pipeline does

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, yaml, azure-devops-pipelines, build-pipeline

I have the following code in my YAML file

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - WVD/*
```

When I complete a pull request and the code gets committed back to main it should run if its in the WVD directory. (WVD dir is in the root of the repo)

If I edit the pipeline > Triggers and override the YAML and select the main branch and path filter WVD/* it works?
[Editing Trigger on Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ7VR.png)

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the Pipeline trigger screen, you can either override or use YAML but there is a tick box to allow Continuous Intergration.

Make sure you have this enabled and then remove the override tickbox from the trigger settings or CI\CD will be disabled even tho you are specifying to use YAML. :)
[Azure Pipeline Trigger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GowM7.png)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.